# Rails - use a JSON that is returned from an AJAX form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have a Rails form that when submitted, goes to the URL `/evaluate` and renders a JSON string. How do I make this form use AJAX and return the value to be used on the current page?

What format is the returned value e.g. JSON, params?

NOTE: `Sandie` is an API wrapper.

The `/evaluate` URL links to the controller action `evaluate`:

```
def evaluate
  @code_lesson = CodeLesson.find(params[:code_lesson][:id])
  @language = Language.find(@code_lesson.language_id).slug
  @sandie = Sandie.new(language: @language)
  @code = @sandie.evaluate(code: params[:code_lesson][:user_code])
  render inline: "<%= @code.inspect %>"
end
```

The form is like this:

```
<%= form_for @code_lesson, url: new_submission_path, 
                           method: :post, 
                           remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_code, value: '' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: @code_lesson.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Code", class: "btn btn-success", id: "submit-code" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I render the output of this action to be used in the page?

Answer (score 0):

Here, catch a [link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) to Rails Guide: Working with JavaScript. You're going to write your own JavaScript handler for AJAX success. Article gives pretty straightforward example:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_post").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#new_post").append xhr.responseText
  ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#new_post").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

As you can see, your data will be passed to `ajax:success` handler. This is where you going to make some transformations on your page.